# Setting XY tolerance in a feature class doesn't prevent creation of vertices distanced less than the defined tolerance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tolerance

What I want is to do is to create a feature class where I am not allowed to create a new vertex if it's closer than 5m. to another vertex.

In a geodatabase, I create a feature class setting the XY **tolerance** to 5 meters, but that doesn't achieve the result. I am still able to create vertices within 5m. from each other. Setting the **resolution** to 5m. does achieve it, but that is done by snapping to an underlying 5x5m grid, which significantly affects positional accuracy (it might move the vertrx to an undesired grid edge, far from where my original positioning was).

Are there any additional settings to consider?

Is there something I have not understood correctly about XY tolerance?

Do I perhaps need to approach this in a different way?